# Passing generic object to function [golang]

Tags: go

I find myself doing the following very often, and would like to reduce the replication.

```
var customer model.Customer

decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
decoder.DisallowUnknownFields()
err := decoder.Decode(&customer)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print(err)
}

doSomethingWith(customer)
```

I want to write a simple function that can take in `r.Body` and some object to map to i.e. `model.Customer`

So something like (not valid golang)

```
func fromJson(body io.ReadCloser, obj T) {
    var obj

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(body)
    decoder.DisallowUnknownFields()
    err := decoder.Decode(&obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `interface{}` or wait for [generics](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43651):

```golang
func fromJson(body io.ReadCloser, obj interface{}) error {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(body)
    decoder.DisallowUnknownFields()
    return decoder.Decode(obj)
}
```

For example, if you check [the doc for `Decode`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode), you can see that it uses this mechanism, which is commonplace in Go.

Working sample: https://play.golang.org/p/D3GDKtUJxHC